# How to play youtube video (youtube embed url) on webView

Tags: android, webview, youtube

i can't get youtube videos to play. when i click the play button, the video shows only black screen. does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

I've tried this

```
WebView content = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
content.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
});
String mimeType = "text/html";
String encoding = "UTF-8";
String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/vS6mwyHNacA?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
content.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
rootLinearLayout.addView(content);
```

and this

```
WebView content = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
content.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
});
String url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/vS6mwyHNacA?rel=0";
content.loadUrl(url);
rootLinearLayout.addView(content);
```

Still it won't play.
is Flash required? I don't want to use Flash for playback

Comment: Flash player required in mobile

Comment: Welcome.  U can like my comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out my android device for testing needs flash to make it work.
that code works on android 4.0 or newer.
all i need to do is check the sdk version. if 4.0 or newer, play it on webview
if not, use youtube intent

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(IDryIceWebConstants.YOUTUBE_EMBED_BASE_URL+video.getYoutube_code()));
startActivity(intent);
```